# Android, adding a menu to an activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

I want to add a menu to my main activity. When I start my application, all shows up correctly but the menu. What I'm doing wrong?

This is my activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is part of the MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menu1:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked Menu 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.menu2:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked Menu 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This is the styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And for last, this is the menu_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu1"
        android:title="Option 1" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu2"
        android:title="Optiion 2" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Is the ActionBar visible?

Comment: I think yes? If not how I can enable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your activity extending from AppCompatActivity?
Extending from AppCompatActivity allows you to set the toolbar using the method `setSupportActionBar` check this first.

If not, the 'easy' way would be to use a theme that by default provides you an AppBar (ending with .DarkActionBar for example)

Comment: It was extending from Activity, I've changed to AppCompatActivity and now seems to work

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `toolbar` in your activity_main.xml and in your MainActivity.java in the onCreate add this:
`setSupportActionBar(yourToolbarId);`

Comment: Hi, I've added a toolbar into activity_main.xml, but "setSupportActionBar(yourToolbarId);" isn't recognized as a method

Comment: I have solved this by changing "public class MainActivity extends Activity" to "public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity" on MainActivity.java

Comment: Great. Have a nice day.